# Has the configuration of the new version of mybatis changed? What should I do to fill in the time

Tags: mybatis

I need a mybatis plugin to fill in the time. Previously, I only needed to obtain one parameter and change it. Now, I have upgraded the version of mybatis using<org. mybatis. spring. boot

org. mybatis. spring. boot

mybatis spring boot starter

3.0.2

The invocation. getArgs() in mybatis [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4HFc.jpg) obtains three parameters

How can I reassign values?

[old use mybatis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4HFc.jpg)

[currently use mybatis + Mybatis Dynamic SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgsaZ.png)

[currently use mybatis + Mybatis Dynamic SQL 2 get param](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3VKr.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE7iQ.jpg)

[questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/on5Cf.jpg)

[Implemented functionality, but felt a bit redundant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znS01.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Configuration has not changed. `DefaultInsertStatementProvider` contains a generated insert statement and a matched row. The `record` value is a synonym for `row` - they point to the same object. But `record` is deprecated and will be removed eventually.

Bottom line - change the value in the `row`.

Comment: When I used to use mybatis, the parameters passed by the interceptor were passed by reference. I can use:
Object paramObj=invoice. getArgs() [1];

Comment: Obtain the parameters passed and directly change them, as these parameters are in the form of reference passing.

Comment: Now I use mybatis+mybatis dynamic SQL, and these passed parameters are encapsulated in the DefaultInsertStatementProvider object, which is a value passing form with two different addresses.

Comment: passing form with two different addresses. I cannot change the data in the pass by simply and roughly obtaining the parameters directl

Comment: The method I use to obtain parameters now has also become:
Object paramObj=((DefaultInsertStatementProvider) invocation. getArgs() [1]). getRow()

Comment: I want to use interceptors to achieve some repetitive work of automatically filling data, which requires dynamic parameter changes, but currently I cannot find a suitable interface

Comment: Java is always pass by reference. When you switched to using MyBatis Dynamic SQL, you now have the row embedded in the DefaultInsertStatementProvider. You can change values in the row in your interceptor by obtaining a reference to the row - getRow() as you show above. What is the problem? You seem to have figured out how to do this.

Comment: I just tried again and Java is indeed passed by reference. The problem is that I changed the value, but the SQL statement has not changed yet

Comment: I have added the pictures in the questions link at the end of the question. Click to view them

Comment: If I want to modify the SQL statement, I can only reflect it again ((DefaultInsertStatementProvider<?>) args [1]) because I cannot find the ((DefaultInsertStatementProvider<?>) args [1]). setInsertStatement() function

Comment: That is to say, the operation of adding default fill values for fields needs to be divided into two steps: using reflection to modify the content, and using reflection to modify the InsertStatement in the content

Comment: It feels quite troublesome, and there are also various scenarios to modify, add, and delete. For compatibility, I may need to make multiple judgments in this statement

Comment: Is it because I didn't find the right method? I remember if I only used mybatis as an interceptor, his array mapping method only needed to change the array, and the internal SQL conversion didn't need to be modified by hand. Using mybatis dynamic seems a bit cumbersome when it comes to interceptor operations. Did I use it incorrectly?

Comment: //mybatis
            //get param
            Object param = invocation.getArgs()[1];
            //update
            Field[] declaredFields =  param.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : declaredFields) {
                System.out.println(field.getName());
                field.setAccessible(true);
                if ("id".equalsIgnoreCase(field.getName()) && ObjectUtils.isEmpty(field.get(param))) {
                    setValue(param, field, new IdWorker(0, 1).nextId());
                }
            }

Comment: //mybatis dynamic
            //get param
            Object param2 = ((DefaultInsertStatementProvider<?>)invocation.getArgs()[1]).getRow();
            //update
            Field[] declaredFields2 =  param.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : declaredFields2) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                if ("id".equalsIgnoreCase(field.getName()) && ObjectUtils.isEmpty(field.get(param))) {
                    setValue(param, field, new IdWorker(0, 1).nextId());
                }
            }

Comment: //mybatis dynamic //update sql
            //update invocation.getArgs()[0]
            //update ((DefaultInsertStatementProvider<?>)invocation.getArgs()[1]) InsertStatement()